In django how can I resolve a reverse error when copying text from an html table row and attempting to write it to a text file?
I have a django app with a page that shows a data table of text strings populated from a model.
Each string is a website url.  I need to be able to click on any one of these rows and have that url string written to a text file.
What I have so far results in a 'reverse' error as soon as the server tries to load the home page.
Here is the model:
class Environment(models.Model):
url = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=True, 
blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.url

Here is the view for the home page, which displays a list of urls populated from the model:
def home(request):
    envs = Environment.objects.all()
    f = open('environment.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    context = {'title':'Home Page',
        'year':datetime.now().year, 'envs':envs, 'file_content':file_content}
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)

here is the view for the writing of the url text to the file:
def write_url_to_file(request, url):
    with open('environment.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(url)
        file.close()
    return redirect('app:home')

Here is the url.py:
from django.urls import path, reverse
from app import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('write-url/<str:url>/', views.write_url_to_file, name='write_url_to_file'),
    path('report/', views.report, name='report'),
    path('extract-and-display/', views.extract_and_display, name='extracted_elements'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('smoke_tests/', views.smoke_tests, name='smoke'),
    path('repairs/', views.repairs, name='repairs'),]

Here is the template tag.  The idea is to click a url to write it to a text file:
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Environment</th>
</tr>
{% for env in envs %}
<tr>
    <td><a href="{% url 'app:write_url_to_file' env.url %}">{{ env.url }}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

I have tried various things such as changing the template tage to {% url 'app:write_url_to_file' url=env.url %}, but it still results in reverse error.
In the view I have also tried redirect(reverse('app:home')) but still the same error on loading the home page.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Show the urls.py.

urls.py added above

<str:…> matches every character, except the slash, so most URLs will probably not work. Use the <path:…> path converter [Django-doc]:
path(
    'write-url/<path:url>/',
    views.write_url_to_file,
    name='write_url_to_file',
),

That works perfectly!  I have learnt something new.  Thank you very much for your help.  I appreciate it.
